# AngularJS Passing scope between controllers Performance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, profiling

I have two AngularJS controllers where controller 1 is always visible in the view and controller 2 can change from view to view. I need to make sure that controller 1 has access to some scope variables. So on loading if I pass entire scope of controller 2 to controller 1 will it harm the performance of the page?

Comment: Passing scopes is probably not what you want (*I'm not even sure how you'd do that*). Have you tried putting the necessary data in shared angular services?

Comment: We can do that using services or rootscope. my point is I should be able to modify some scope variables from controller 1 without changing much code of controller 2. Controller one does not have any scope variables of its own.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing scope between controllers is possible, but only through inheritence. I'm pretty sure you can't "send" a scope to another controller and replace it completely.

I would suggest either broadcasting events with data between controllers, or storing them inside AngularJS services (`factory`). Since these are singletons, the data will stay intact as long as you don't reboot the app.

EDIT: In regards to performance, even if the gain is extremely small, I'd suggest using a service to store the data. This way it's acting as a simple DTO, and doesn't have to be double-binding (if you don't need it) which means the `$digest` cycle is a bit faster.

Regards

Comment: hmm but this is not true. You can share scope by using rootscope or a factory. But I am more concerned about performance.

Comment: You're still not "sharing" scope in that sense. `$rootScope` is the mother of all scopes. All new scopes are instantiated as children of `$rootScope`, and possible scopes between the new scope and `$rootScope`. As long as you're sure that controller 2 is a child of controller 1, you can't access scope-specific data on controller 1 from controller 2. I'd suggest using services as i wrote, or store them on `$rootScope`. That's your designchoice :)

Comment: Yes I am doing what you are saying. But my question is will that method  harm performance?

Comment: By saving stuff on the `$rootScope`. Barely. The performance upside to store it in a service is that the data doesn't have to go through every `$digest` cycle